# cannot access locale messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have defined two properties file inside resources directory. 
they are:-
**messages_es_ES.properties**

```
message.welcome=Se registro correctamente. Le enviaremos
```

**messages_en.properties**

```
message.welcome=Welcome To our main login page
```

and now i am trying access this message on my html page by using thymeleaf like this:-

```
<h1 th:text="#{message.welcome}"></h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
  Obcaecati voluptatibus odio vero et quasi, incidunt quae eaque 
  maiores repellendus totam placeat autem quam eligendi ut in 
  veritatis. Dolores, repellendus dolor.</p>
```

and my config file:-

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;


    public MvcConfig() {
        super();
    }


    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return  localeResolver;
    }


    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        return validator;
    }

}
```

[image]
[image]

why is it not showing welcome message ?

Comment: Your message files path is /resources/messages_en?

Comment: you can check the above image that i uploaded.

Comment: Check my asnwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code structure, it looks like you move your `messages` to subdirectory: `/messages/messages_en.properties` hence the default `messageSource` does not see that.

You need to override your default `messageSource`:

```
@Bean
@Primary // Must use this to override message source
public static MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messages/messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(true);
    return messageSource;
 }
```

Put this to your `MvcConfig` class

Comment: well this actually worked after i edited classpath:messages/messages to classpath:messages( as i din't create any directory, just added messages files in resource directory). i would like to know how this bean is actually working?